# Writing a discord bot using discord.js, but getting error when attempting to connect to database

Tags: javascript, discord.js

My code looks like this

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

const token = process.env['token']
const password = process.env['pw']

const { createConnection } = require('mysql');
const database = createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: '3306',
  user: 'root',
  password: password,
  database: 'db2',
  charset: 'utf8mb4'
});

database.connect();
```

I'm still trying to learn how to read these error messages, so I can't tell if the problem is with the mysql install or with the code or the connection itself.

[Here's the error from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qOmN.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `ECONNREFUSED` error, this is indicating that for whatever reason it can not connect to the database. Seeing that you are getting a -111 error code I would guess that your MySQL instance was not running (or not running on the specified ip/port combination) based on [the MariaDB troubleshooting page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/troubleshooting-connection-issues/).

As for how to read those errors can be a bit of search work, but it will always indicate where in your code the error originated from. In this case it was the 4th line: `at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/file/bot.js:17:10)`.
The last part here is really helpful. This tells us that it originated from the file `bot.js` at line 17, character 10. Or in other words the error came from calling the `.connect()` function. From there you can use Google to search what could result in that error when calling that function with the error code (the error code is usually somewhere at the bottom of the error message).